# How to send messages through TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

If I have a question about a specific line of code for a different developer, does TFS allow me to send a message to the user referencing that line of code?

Comment: You can add comments to the changeset related to a line of code, configure code reviews and on TFS 2015 you also have Team Rooms. https://www.visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/work/productivity/collaborate-in-a-team-room

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possible with the Team Foundation Server 2010 Power tools. There you can instant message or make team chat rooms.

Here is some info about the team rooms.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/productivity/collaborate-in-a-team-room

It has many options and it will some searching where the option is, but you'll find it within the Power tools